# About Schengen visa

Tags: schengen

I am a student currently studying in Spain for less than 180 days. Is the visa I have a schengen visa? To be specific, when you apply for a Spanish visa does it automatically count as a Schengen visa and you can travel to all Schengen countries freely?

Comment: Do you have "Estados Schengen" on your visa?

Comment: I think it only has "Espana" on it. I am not entirely sure right now because my passport isn't with me right now as I have applied for the US visa.

Comment: If "Estados Schengen" isn't written on the visa, does it mean that I can't travel to other schengen countries?

Comment: Forgot to mention btw my visa is valid for 180 days

Comment: Is it a national "D" category visa from Spain?

Comment: I think so. I don;t remember cause I haven't collected my passport after applying for US visa but I am guessing it should be a "D" category visa and it said that it's valid for 180 days.

Comment: @o.m. What else should it be? The only type of visa valid for 180 days is type D national visas.

Comment: cool.So does it mean that I can use it to travel to other schengen countries even if it says that the visa is valid for "Espana"?